# Solving Palindrome problem in Python without using def statement?

Tags: python

Okay so the problem is:

"I was driving on the highway the other day recently and I happened to notice my odometer. Like most odometers nowadays, it shows six digits, in whole miles only -- no tenths of a mile. So, if my car had 300,000 miles, for example, I'd see 3-0-0-0-0-0. And that's all. Until I drove another mile, at which point it would read 3-0-0-0-0-1. “

"Now, what I saw that day was very interesting. I noticed that the last 4 digits were palindromic, that is they read the same forwards as backwards. For example, "5-4-4-5" is a palindrome. So, my odometer could have read 3-1-5-4-4-5, with those last four digits, starting with the units, then the tens, then the hundreds, and finally the thousands, being the palindrome. “

"One mile later, the last 5 numbers were palindromic. For example, it could have read 3-6-5-4-5-6. “

"One mile after that, the middle 4 out of 6 numbers were palindromic. So, the first and last numbers weren't involved in the palindrome, but the middle 4 were palindromic. “

"And you ready for this? One mile later, all 6 were palindromic! For example, 2-1-3-3-1-2. "

Pretty good, huh? I thought so. So, here again are the conditions. "I noticed that the last 4 digits were palindromic. I drove a mile, and the last 5 were palindromic. I drove another mile and the middle 4 were palindromic, and the ends were not involved. And then one mile later, all 6 digits were palindromic."

The question is, what did the driver see on the odometer when they first looked?

Here's what I believe the answer is but I got to it using def statements. How would I use only a while loop or for loop instead to solve the problem?

```
def has_palindrome(i, start, len):
"""Returns True if the integer i, when written as a string,
contains a palindrome with length (len), starting at index (start).
"""
s = str(i)[start:start+len]
return s[::-1] == s

def check(i):
"""Checks whether the integer (i) has the properties described
in the puzzler.
"""
return (has_palindrome(i, 2, 4)   and
        has_palindrome(i+1, 1, 5) and
        has_palindrome(i+2, 1, 4) and
        has_palindrome(i+3, 0, 6))

def check_all():
"""Enumerates the six-digit numbers and prints any that satisfy the
requirements of the puzzler"""

i = 100000
while i <= 999996:
    if check(i):
        print i
    i = i + 1

print 'The following are the possible odometer readings:'
```

I know so far: I need to use a loop that tries every number between 100000 and 999999 until it finds one that meets all of the conditions. So really just need to specify the conditions in the question as boolean expression, put them into a bunch of if statements, and then put all of that into a while loop right? How would I write out the conditions within just a while loop?

Comment: You are calling "def" four times, so you will have to repeat that four times inside `while` if you're to avoid function.

Comment: A simple analytical solution means no defs :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it's a math or logic, not a programming problem. You have the following sequences of digits:

```
Start: a b c d d c
Mile1: e f g h g f
Mile2: i j k k j l
Mile3: m n o o n m
```

It's pretty clear that `j = n`, `k = o`, and since adding 1 didn't affect the middle digits in the last step, `i = m`:

```
Start: a b c d d c
Mile1: e f g h g f
Mile2: i j k k j l
Mile3: i j k k j i
```

From this, `i = l + 1`. One way to move the palindrome section over between Mile1 and Mile2, we have to carry a digit. That means `f = 9`, and `c = 8`:

```
Start: a b 8 d d 8
Mile1: e 9 g h g 9
Mile2: 1 j k k j 0
Mile3: 1 j k k j 1
```

Now, `b = 9`, `d = g` and `g = 8`:

```
Start: a 9 8 8 8 8
Mile1: e 9 8 h 8 9
Mile2: 1 j k k j 0
Mile3: 1 j k k j 1
```

The rest of the solution can be filed in at this point:

```
Start: 1 9 8 8 8 8
Mile1: 1 9 8 8 8 9
Mile2: 1 9 8 8 9 0
Mile3: 1 9 8 8 9 1
```

And look, not a single `def` anywhere!

Another option is to assume that the digit carry happens between Start and Mile1:

```
Start: a b 9 d d 9
Mile1: e 0 g h g 0
Mile2: 2 j k k j 1
Mile3: 2 j k k j 2
```

In this case, `j = 0`, and `g = j`:

```
Start: a b 9 d d 9
Mile1: e 0 0 h 0 0
Mile2: 2 0 k k 0 1
Mile3: 2 0 k k 0 2
```

For the transformation to hold, `d = 9` must hold too, as well as `b = 9`, after which the remaining digits fall into place:

```
Start: 1 9 9 9 9 9
Mile1: 2 0 0 0 0 0
Mile2: 2 0 0 0 0 1
Mile3: 2 0 0 0 0 2
```

For completeness, here's the result in python:

```
result = 198888
```

Or

```
result = 199999
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inline the function calls to remove the `def` statements. This code also uses a range loop to count over the valid odometer readings, and puts the 4 palindrome checks in a loop (using the built-in `all`) to avoid code duplication:

```
for n in range(100000, 1000000 - 4):
    c = [(n, 2, 5), (n+1, 1, 5), (n+2, 1, 4), (n+3, 0, 5)]
    if all(str(i)[s:e+1] == str(i)[s:e+1][::-1] for i, s, e in c):
        print(n)
```

That's a straight translation of the original code. If you wish to include odometer values starting at `000000`, and include cases where the odometer wraps around, you can adapt the code like this:

```
for n in range(1000000):
    c = [(n, 2, 5), (n+1, 1, 5), (n+2, 1, 4), (n+3, 0, 5)]
    if all(('%06d'%i)[-6:][s:e+1] == ('%06d'%i)[-6:][s:e+1][::-1] for i, s, e in c):
        print(n)
```

Comment: You should be starting at zero and printing numbers zero padded to 6 digits. 000000 is a perfectly valid odometer reading.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're right -- I just translated the code in the question. I now provide a variant that includes all odometer readings (including cases that wrap around).

Comment: Nice. Still, the analytical solution is complete.